# How to add an array of new data to a D3 hierarchy?

Tags: d3.js, tree, hierarchy, circular-dependency

I'm working with a tree of hierarchical data, on the server side. I need to compute some parameters for each branch with scheduled functions after updating the tree hierarchy.

My problem is: how do I take a d3.hierarchy on one side, and an array of new documents on the other, and get a new hierarchy?

here is some data:

```
let collection = [
    { id: 0, rank: 0 },
    { id: 1, parent: 0},
    { id: 2, parent: 0},
    { id: 3, parent: 1},
    { id: 4, parent: 1},
    { id: 5, parent: 1},
    { id: 6, parent: 1},
    { id: 7, parent: 2},
    { id: 8, parent: 2},
    { id: 9, parent: 2},
    { id: 10, parent: 3},
    { id: 11, parent: 3},
    { id: 12, parent: 3},
    { id: 13, parent: 3},
    { id: 14, parent: 4},
    { id: 15, parent: 5},
    { id: 16, parent: 5},
    { id: 17, parent: 6},
    { id: 18, parent: 6},
    { id: 19, parent: 6},
    { id: 20, parent: 6},
    { id: 21, parent: 7},
    { id: 22, parent: 7},
    { id: 23, parent: 7},
    { id: 24, parent: 8},
    { id: 25, parent: 8},
    { id: 26, parent: 9},
    { id: 27, parent: 9},
]

let root = d3
    .stratify()
    .id(d => d.id)
    .parentId(d => d.parent)(collection)

    console.log(root)

vvvvvvvvvvvv prints vvvvvvvvv
Node {
    data: { id: 0, rank: 0 },
    height: 3,
    depth: 0,
    parent: null,
    id: '0',
    children:
     [ Node {
         data: [Object],
         height: 2,
         depth: 1,
         parent: [Circular],
         id: '1',
         children: [Array] } ] }


const newElements = [   
    { id: 28, parent: 16},
    { id: 29, parent: 6},
    { id: 30, parent: 12},
    { id: 31, parent: 19},
    { id: 32, parent: 28},
    { id: 33, parent: 7},
    { id: 34, parent: 33},
]
```

So `root` is the ('object'??) I'm working with on the server, and `newElements` the things I would like to add to `root`.

Comment: Could you share some sample data and expected output?

Comment: I updated the question with some data..

Comment: I guess I'll do brute force with node.each() ..

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do it i.e. no built in D3 functions that I know of. You will probably need to write something on your own.

Comment: Do you have an idea what is the "Node" thing that the console logged? Can I just treat this as an object?

Comment: I'm just going to open the source file of d3.stratify()...

Comment: Node is an object but has special methods attached to it such as those in D3 hierarchy, like `ancestors`, `descendants` etc. Hence it has it's own prototype. Check this https://runkit.com/mbostock/56fed33d8630b01300f72daa